# How to align text to center in an absolutely positioned list element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code,

```css
.testimonial-wrapper {
  background: green;
}

.testimonial {
  max-width: 980px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: grey;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  height: 70px;
}

.testimonial {
  position: relative;
}

li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
}

li.current{
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="testimonial-wrapper">
    <div class="testimonial">
        <ul>
          <li class="current"><div>
            <p>This is the first test message</p>
            </div>  
          </li>
          <li>
            <div>
            <p>I have nothing more to say</p>
          </div></li>
          <li><div>
            <p>again if i could i would</p>
          </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I would like to center the text content within the testimonial container. I tried `p {text-align: center}`, but to no avail. I noticed that when the li is not absolutely positioned, the `text-align: center` worked.

What am I missing, and how can I correct this?

Comment: `ul li div {display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;}`

Comment: hi, thanks for the response, I am not using flex box because of compatibility issues with older IE browsers. Please, it would help if you could remove the down vote.

Comment: What would you do for netscape users, lol?)

Comment: haha...agreed! But it is not up to the developer to decide on what browser that the user should use.

Answer (score 2):

This should work if you just want to center it using current solution without using flexbox, when an element is absolutely positioned, it will no longer have some default properties such as width: 100% for it to works.

Hope it helps!

```css
.testimonial-wrapper {
  background: green;
}

.testimonial {
  max-width: 980px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: grey;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  height: 70px;
}

.testimonial {
  position: relative;
}

li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

li.current{
  top: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="testimonial-wrapper">
    <div class="testimonial">
        <ul>
          <li class="current"><div>
            <p>This is the first test message</p>
            </div>  
          </li>
          <li>
            <div>
            <p>I have nothing more to say</p>
          </div></li>
          <li><div>
            <p>again if i could i would</p>
          </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The cause of your problem is the li not taking the full width as it is positioned `absolute`

So here's a way to achieve what you want

```css
.testimonial-wrapper {
  background: green;
}

.testimonial {
  max-width: 980px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  height: 70px;
}

.testimonial {
  position: relative;
}

li {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

li.current{
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="testimonial-wrapper">
    <div class="testimonial">
        <ul>
          <li class="current"><div>
            <p>This is the first test message</p>
            </div>  
          </li>
          <li>
            <div>
            <p>I have nothing more to say</p>
          </div></li>
          <li><div>
            <p>again if i could i would</p>
          </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped